# Run multiple times js stopcounter at the same page

Tags: multiple-instances

I found this js stopcounter and I would like to add it in multiple input fields in the same page depended an id varible, I suppose that is easy but how can I do that?
e.g

```
<input type="text"  id="1"  value="" />
<input type="button" value="Start/Stop" onclick="startstoptimer(1)">
<input type="reset" onclick="resettimer(1)">
<input type="text"  id="2"  value="" />
<input type="button" value="Start/Stop" onclick="startstoptimer(2)">
<input type="reset" onclick="resettimer(2)">
```

and so  on...

The original code is

```
<head>
<script>
<!--

var millisec = 0;
var seconds = 0;
var timer;

function display(){

  if (millisec>=9){
     millisec=0
     seconds+=1
  }
  else
     millisec+=1
     document.d.d2.value = seconds + "." + millisec;
     timer = setTimeout("display()",100);
  }

function starttimer() {
    
  if (timer > 0) {
    return;
  }
  display();    
}
function stoptimer() {
  clearTimeout(timer);
  timer = 0;
}

function startstoptimer() {
  if (timer > 0) {
     clearTimeout(timer);
     timer = 0;
  } else {
     display();
  }
}

function resettimer() {
    stoptimer();
    millisec = 0;
    seconds = 0;
}


-->
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h5>Millisecond Javascript Timer</h5>
<form name="d">
<input type="text" size="8" name="d2">
<input type="button" value="Start/Stop" onclick="startstoptimer()">
<input type="reset" onclick="resettimer()">
</form>

</body></html>
```

I tried this but does not work well. The error is ( Cannot set properties of null (setting 'value'))

````
<!--

var millisec = 0;
var seconds = 0;
var timer;
var id;
function display(id){
  if (millisec>=9){
     millisec=0
     seconds+=1
  }
  else
     millisec+=1
     //document.id.value = seconds + "." + millisec;
     document.getElementById(id).value =   seconds + ":" + millisec  ; 
     timer = setTimeout("display(id)",100);
  }

function starttimer(id) {
    
  if (timer > 0) {
    return;
  }
  display(id);  
}
function stoptimer(id) {
  clearTimeout(timer);
  timer = 0;
}

function startstoptimer(id) {
  if (timer > 0) {
     clearTimeout(timer);
     timer = 0;
  } else {
     display(id);
  }
}

function resettimer(id) {
    stoptimer(id);
    millisec = 0;
    seconds = 0;
}
-->
</script>```
````